# Formatting MySQL date

Tags: mysql

If I have a MySQL date as follows `2012-07-29 22:02:50`, and I want this to be formatted to `Jul 29 2012`, is there an easy way to do this using a SELECT statement?

Currently my sql statement looks like this:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT Id, DATE_FORMAT(Date,\"%Y-%m-%d\") AS Date FROM infoTable WHERE credential = '$credential'");
```

This outputs `2012-07-29`

Comment: Do you really mean `Jul 7 2012`?  Or do you mean `Jul 29 2012`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $rs = mysql_query("SELECT Id, DATE_FORMAT(Date,\"%b %e %Y\") AS Date FROM infoTable WHERE credential = '$credential'");
```

[Source](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)

Answer (score 0):

Change the DATE_FORMAT expression to:

```
DATE_FORMAT(Date,\"%b %e %Y\")
```

You can view all the possible formatting options at the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) reference page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT Id, DATE_FORMAT(Date,\"%b %e %Y\") AS Date FROM infoTable WHERE credential = '$credential'");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp